# Facebook authentication from within an iFrame running on a partners site (iFrame is not running on my site or Facebook)

Tags: facebook, authentication, iframe

We want to put our content within an iFrame running on a partners website.  Is it possible to do Facebook authentication in said iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

To keep Facebook authentication working, Facebook applications require that the application id you are using is running on the domain plugged into the applications settings box.  So if they are different domains (subdomains of the same domain are ok) it will not work.